# Can shield cap the damage you take?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I know you can kill someone with full health and shield in one shot with a sniper rifle headshot for example, and the damage trap does 150 damage. However, I've also heard the hit number has a special appearance when your opponent runs out of shield. Can shield ever reduce the damage you take, or is it a simple extension of health? For example, if you had 10 shield and full health and got hit for 30 damage, would you be left with 0 shield and full health or 0 shield and 80 health?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just an extension of your health and they both work the same way except for fall and storm damage. I don't believe there is a special appearance for the damage number itself, but you can hear a sound when someone nearby loses their shield.